# Converting 14bit to 8 bit and back

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have written some C code where I have a 14-bit number that I want to convert to 2 bit bytes where the two msb's have to be zero. In other words 16383 (In binary 111111111111111) should come out as MSB = 00111111 and LSB = 11111111. The code I am using is shown below. Is this correct?

```
dataMSB = (number>>8) & 0x00FF;
dataLSB = number & 0x00FF;
```

Then I have another 14-bit number that is input as two 8-bit bytes where the two lsb's need to be thrown away. Here I am pretty certain I am doing it incorrectly but am unsure. Any ideas?

```
number = dataMSB << 8;
number += dataLSB;
```

Comment: Why do you think that in inverse conversion you need to throw 2 LSB's?
As I can see here actually 2 MSB's are odd in the conversion.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the two lsb's need to be twrown away"? Can you give an example?

Comment: Your code is working perfect. by the way, what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

A simple test on [IDEOne](http://www.ideone.com) reveals that your code performs correctly.

```
int number = 16000;

int dataMSB = (number >> 8) & 0x00FF;
int dataLSB = number & 0x00FF;

// This prints 62 and 128, which is an expected result.
// 62  = 00111110
// 128 = 10000000
cout << dataMSB << " " << dataLSB << endl;

number = dataMSB << 8;
number += dataLSB;

// This prints 16000 as expected.
cout << number << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly working if we use converted `LSB` and `MSB` to convert back.

From your question, I assume that if data MSB and LSB are user inputted value, then you need to throw away 2 bits from `dataMSB`, *not from `dataLSB`*. For that you may need to do the following:

```
number = (dataMSB & 0x003F)<< 8;
number += dataLSB;
```

and it will give you perfect result also if `dataMSB` is 8 bit long, for instance 255.

I used the following to test. binary is printed in reverse:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BIT(i) (1<<(i))

void PrintBin(const int num)
{
    int value = num;
    char bin[17]="0000000000000000";
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<16;i++)
        bin[i]= (value & BIT(i))? '1':'0';
    bin[16]='\0';
    printf("%d::%s\n",num,bin);
}

void main()
{
    int dataMSB, dataLSB;
    int number = 16383;
    int number1 =0;
    PrintBin(number);
    dataMSB = (number>>8) & 0x00FF;
    dataLSB = number & 0x00FF;
    PrintBin(dataMSB);
    PrintBin(dataLSB);
    dataMSB =255;
    number1 =(dataMSB & 0x003F) << 8;
    number1 += dataLSB;
    PrintBin(number1);
}
```